# Excel Dates Stored as Text

Tags: excel, date

I have a series of dates in excel stored as text like D/M/YYYY. I need them converted to dates and formatted as M/D/YYYY. I have tried datevalue, no go. Thoughts?

Comment: Dates are integers so if your regional settings are `D/M/YYYY` using the function `VALUE` should convert them to a number and then just apply the new format you wish

Comment: If they are ALL text, you can use the `Data=>Text to Columns` wizard and convert them in place, specifying no delimiters at step 2 and the `DMY` format at step 3. Then set the column  numberformat to `m/d/yyy`, If some are text and some are not, then you've got other problems, so clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=DATE(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,2),TAKE(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,-1),,-1),TAKE(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,-1),,1))
```

or

```
=DATE(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,3),INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,2),INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,1))
```

Result:

[image]

Don't forget to format `C1` cell to your desired date format.

Comment: The index formula worked swimmingly user11222393. I did have a mixture of text dates and dates, so this formula was easy to plug in where required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Column A are dates in format `dd/mm/yyyy` forced as text values, not dates. Formula in column B is just `=VALUE(A1)` and applied cell format as `mm/dd/yyyy`

If this does not work properly, you need to manipulate the string using different functions:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)+1,SEARCH("/",A1,SEARCH("/",A1)+1)-(SEARCH("/",A1)+1)),LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)-1))
```

[image]